# How to use container (and services) in Symfony 5 migrations?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine, migration

I'm trying to get the container - and a service through it - in a migration (using Symfony 5.1.2 and doctrine/migrations 3.0.1). But when I try to create a class based on [this example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations) like this:

```
class Version20200717072537 extends AbstractMigration implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function postUp(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        $fooService = $this->container->get('app.foo');
        //...
    }
}
```

... and I try to run migrations, I get a `Call to a member function get() on null` error.
So for some reason container is null.

I also tried replacing the `use ContainerAwareTrait;` with the actual `setContainer` function that I found in it, and it looks like the `setContainer` function is never called.

I'm pretty sure some time ago I was able to get the container from the migrations (maybe in Symfony 3 or 4?) based on the example I linked above, but now I don't know if this is the expected behavior in Symfony 5, or a bug, or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The exemple you showed is based on migration 1.3 and not the 3.0 version

Comment: And since using SF 5.x why not using directly autowiring and inject the class instead of having all the container in your migration

Comment: Yes, I know it's from 1.3, and I'm using 3.0, I just thought that this might not have changed. I also had the idea to autowire the migrations, but somewhere, I've read that it is not recommended (but sorry can't remember the reason and source for this).

Comment: I also went your way, i.e. `implement ContainerAwareInterface`. `$this->container` was not `null`, but I couldn't get my service out of the container until I made that service `public` (not the recommended way to do things, but it's simpler than the `MigrationFactory` approach). (My setup: Symfony: 5.4, doctrine/migrations: 3.5.1)

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comments documentation related to the old version. But now you can do it with `MigrationFactory`.

You need to create your own `MigrationFactory` class, which will inject some service into your migrations. Starts from 3.4 Symfony all services a private, so you can't get them from the container.

doctrine_migrations.yaml

```
services:
    'Doctrine\Migrations\Version\MigrationFactory': 'App\Doctrine\Migrations\MigrationFactory'
```

MigrationFactory

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MigrationFactory implements \Doctrine\Migrations\Version\MigrationFactory
{
    /** @var Connection */
    private $connection;

    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var SomeService
     */
    private $service;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection, LoggerInterface $logger, SomeService $service)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->logger     = $logger;
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function createVersion(string $migrationClassName) : AbstractMigration
    {
        $migration = new $migrationClassName(
            $this->connection,
            $this->logger
        );

        // or you can ommit this check
        if ($migration instanceof SomeInterface) {
            $migration->setService($this->service);
        }

        return $migration;
    }
}
```

Migration

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Doctrine\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20200717112426 extends AbstractMigration implements SomeInterface
{
    private $service;

    public function setService(SomeService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    }

    public function postUp(Schema $schema): void
    {
        $this->service->someMethod();
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks !
See https://www.goetas.com/blog/multi-namespace-migrations-with-doctrinemigrations-30/#extra%3A-custom-migration-factories-aka-decorating-services for more information also

Answer (score 3):

###### Since DoctrineMigrationsBundle >= 3.1 you only need to implement the `ContainerAwareInterface` and use the `ContainerAwareTrait`.

```
final class Version20230508085223 extends AbstractMigration implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        $service = $this->container->get(App\Services\Service::class);
    }
}
```

[This PR](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/pull/368) introduced the [`ContainerAwareMigrationFactory`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/3.1.0/MigrationsFactory/ContainerAwareMigrationFactory.php) which, by default, decorates the `doctrine.migrations.migrations_factory` service.

So if you just need the service container and don't want/need to inject specific services into your custom migration factory decorator, you can remove your custom migration factory decorator altogether, as its job is now done by default.

Comment: Just a note that this approach is deprecated in symfony 6.4 and onwards and right now there is no suggested way to do this: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/521